# Challenges while writing data in PDF with C# using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

My requirement is to write data in PDF file that is given by the client.
This PDF has few textboxes, radio buttons and check boxes.

I am able to write data in the given PDF file with itextsharp (5.5.5.0) using C#, but I am having three challenges here

1. Radio buttons - I am able to select a radio button but somehow it is selecting as "X", how do I fix it?
2. After I write data in PDF, the PDF becomes read-only and I am not able to change the data. How do I maintain the state of the PDF as writable after I populate data in PDF through C#?
3. Depending upon Radio Button selection, PDF should display different textboxes, I mean if I select RadioButton 1 through C# then the PDF should display TextBox1 and If I select RadioButton 2 through C# the PDF should display TextBox2, how do I achieve this?

I am using this code to write in PDF and selecting the RadioButton

```
string pdfTemplate = @"C:\Users\Desktop\vstryout\Form_SH-7 - Copy.pdf";
            string newFile = @"C:\Users\Desktop\vstryout\Form_SH-7 - Copy-1.pdf";
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite), '\0', false);
            AcroFields formFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

            foreach (var de in formFields.Fields)
            {
                if (de.Key == "Form5_Dtls[0].Page1[0].Heading[0].CompName_C[0]")
                {
                    formFields.SetField("Form5_Dtls[0].Page1[0].Heading[0].CompName_C[0]", "Company Name");
                }

                if (de.Key.ToString() == "Form5_Dtls[0].Page1[0].Heading[0].CompanyAdd_C[0]")
                {
                    formFields.SetField("Form5_Dtls[0].Page1[0].Heading[0].CompanyAdd_C[0]", "Company Address");
                }

                if (de.Key.ToString() == "Form5_Dtls[0].Page1[0].SRN[0].SRN_C[0]")
                {
                    formFields.SetField("Form5_Dtls[0].Page1[0].SRN[0].SRN_C[0]", "SRN");
                }

                if (de.Key.ToString() == "Form5_Dtls[0].Page1[0].Resolution[0].DateOfMeeting_D[0]")
                {
                    formFields.SetField("Form5_Dtls[0].Page1[0].Resolution[0].DateOfMeeting_D[0]", "16/12/2010");
                }

                if (de.Key.ToString() == "Form5_Dtls[0].Page1[0].Resolution[0].OrdinarySpecial_R[0]")
                {
                    formFields.SetField("Form5_Dtls[0].Page1[0].Resolution[0].OrdinarySpecial_R[0]", "Yes");
                }


                if (de.Key.ToString() == "Form5_Dtls[0].Page1[0].Heading[0].PurposeofForm[0]")
                {
                    if (formFields.GetFieldType("Form5_Dtls[0].Page1[0].Heading[0].PurposeofForm[0]").ToString() == "3")
                    {
                        string[] str = formFields.GetAppearanceStates("Form5_Dtls[0].Page1[0].Heading[0].PurposeofForm[0]");
                        formFields.SetField("Form5_Dtls[0].Page1[0].Heading[0].PurposeofForm[0]", str[2]);
                    }
                }
            }
            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            pdfStamper.Close();
            pdfReader.Close();
```

FYI...I do not have to create any fields in the PDF, fields are already there in the PDF file, I just need to put data in these fields.

Regards

Comment: Some example of your code would be nice.

Comment: Remove the `pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;`, that should prevent the document form becoming read-only.

Comment: I have removed pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true; but now it is not populating any data in the fields and is still not editable